# Memoryleak or not - linked list

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, struct, linked-list

I have created a program based on a linked-list where every node is a struct that holds an 8-byte integer and a pointer to the next node. The queue follows FIFO. It seems to work fine but I suspect the program could suffer from some kind of memory-leak or memory fragmentation in the heap. I may be wrong - hopefully!!! When a node is deleted in FIFO-order I use the library function **free** where I put the pointer of that node. I also set the pointer to the first and last node to NULL when the linked-list is empty.

But there is a thing that I do not understand and could be sign of a memory-leak.

Let say I create 3 nodes that holds 3 integers. The memoryaddresses of these nodes is as follows:

205888

206032

206056

Now I decide to delete these nodes and free resources to these three nodes.

And when I startover to add nodes - the first node do not start at address 205888, it starts at address 206056.

Does this reveal a memory-leak in my program?

*Here is the function the destroy the node. It takes as argument the address to nodes that is to be deleted*

```
 static int destroy_node(node *node_ref) {
    int data = 0;
    data = node_ref->data;
    free(node_ref);
    return data;
}
```

and the struct

```
    typedef struct node {
      int data;
      struct node *next;
    } node;
```

Comment: If node is a linked list node, it will probably have a ->next or ->prev or ->link pointer somewhere. Maybe you could add the definieion for node to your question?

Comment: When you delete a node, you should have a `node->back = node->next` statement to maintain your link as a chain!

Comment: `malloc` and friends never guarantee that they will re-allocate a previously freed node immediately.  Most implementations don't. So what you are seeing is not indicative of a memory leak.  Of course, what you've shown us is not sufficient to rule one out.

Comment: If you suspect memory leak you try to write test program that will massively add and remove elements from list and run it while monitoring memory usage. You should learn how to debug and test your programs.

Answer (score 1):

If you free an area of memory, you cannot be sure what will be allocated for you next. So this behaviour basically does not show a memory leak.

There may be a memory leak in your code but you can not detect it using address of the allocated node.

To detect memory leak in your code you need tools like `Valgrind`

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn sorry, i wanted to use the word "not". Now made an edit

Comment: +1, memory allocators use a myriad strategies to get you memory, the exact address you get is unpredictable

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the algorithm in the heap.  Strictly speaking, this is "indeterminant" and out of your control.  It could be a sign, but it's not evidence.